# GPU accelerated apps go unresponsive after waking from sleep. (Nvidia)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, suspend, 23.10

Weird problem I have on ubuntu 23.10/i3wm. Whenever I put the computer to sleep using `systemctl sleep`, and I wake it up, a lot of the previously opened GPU accelerated apps just go unresponsive/blank and need restarting (apps like Godot, browser, discord, Spotify, among others that have visual bugs but focusing them makes them rerender and fixes the problem). What could cause this problem/how can I fix it?

Here is some h/w-info:

- **GPU**: msi nvidia gtx 1650 super
- **Driver** **version**: 545
- **OS**: ubuntu 23.10 x64
- **Kernel**: 6.5.0-25-generic